# How to express this integral in the Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

dear All!

I'm a beginner in Mathematica coding, and now trying to find out the following (numerical) integration using Mathematica:
\begin{align}
   g(\mu) := \int_0^1 \sum_{i=1}^{K} [x f(0.05+0.95x; \mu_i) \prod_{j \neq i} F(x; \mu_j)] dx
\end{align}
where $\mu = (\mu_1, ... , \mu_K)$ is a $k$-vector, and $F(x; \theta), f(x; \theta)$ are given functions, i.e.
\begin{align}
   & F(x; \theta) = \Phi[\theta - \Phi^{-1}(1 - \frac{x}{2})]; \\ 
   & f(x; \theta) = e^{-\frac{\theta^2}{2}} \cosh(\theta \Phi^{-1}(1 - \frac{x}{2}))
\end{align}
The Mathematica code for the two functions are:

```
F[x_, \[Theta]_] := 1 - CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],  1 - x/2] - \[Theta]] + CDF[NormalDistribution[0,1], -InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1],  1 - x/2] - \[Theta]]
f[x_, \[Theta]_] := Exp[-\[Theta]^2/2] * Cosh[\[Theta] * InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1 - x/2]]
```

I know how to product all elements in the list using `Times`, but what is the summation of production like in the integral? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 4):

```
k = 5;
Integrate[
 Sum[x*f[0.05 + 0.95 x, μ[i]]*
   Product[F[x, μ[j]], {j, Complement[Range[k], {i}]}], {i, 
   k}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!!! But how do you define vector here? I claim in Mathematica as "\mu = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}", but cannot extract element using "\mu[i]".

Comment: See [the documentation of Part](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html).